# Chrome Extension: how can I redirect a resource request to a filesystem: url?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, html5-filesystem

I have a Chrome extension that basically functions like an advanced "offline mode", where I save all resources requested, and can provide them later when the user requests the url cached resource.

I'm using the webRequest API, and mostly things are working:

1. The extension is hitting all events I'm registering for
2. The extension is saving files using the HTML5 filesystem API correctly, and I have found the files stored correctly on my machine.
3. The extension is able to redirect requests in the `onBeforeRequest` listener to **other http: requests**
4. I am able to access my stored files in Chrome through the **`filesystem:`** protocol (like filesystem:chrome-extension://<myExtHere>/persistent/<filename>)

However, I am unable to **redirect webRequest requests to urls using the `filesystem:` protocol**.  When I try, I get an `onErrorOccurred` event (error below.)

**How can I redirect a chrome webRequest to a `filesystem:chrome-extension://` url?** or, failing that,
**How can I redirect a Chrome extension to a local file that the same extension created?**

Here is the full error details object, in case it helps.

```
error: "net::ERR_ABORTED"
frameId: 0
fromCache: false
method: "GET"
parentFrameId: -1
requestId: "22557"
tabId: 6
timeStamp: 1386874360306.4211
type: "main_frame"
url: "http://<redacted, but correct.>"
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help some..

```
return { redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("/your/local/storage.jpg") }
```

Comment: I've got that part down... the issue now is that chrome won't load files directly from the chrome-extension:// protocol, and while it will load files from the filesystem: protocol, the redirector in the extension seems to be thrown off by the filesystem: protocol.

Comment: when you say won't load, what type of error are you getting / how are you accessing the url ? using a get request ? or is it an image ?